# How to display additional data like location and members of the meeting in the react scheduler apart from title, startDate,endDate?

Tags: reactjs, api, calendar, scheduler

I am currently displaying the title, start time, and end time in the event scheduler. But I want to display additional data like the location of the meeting and the names of the people in it.
Are there any specific tags or attributes for react-scheduler just like title,startTime and endTime??

```
const Calendar2 = () => 
{

  const [posts,setPosts]=useState([]);
  const [postData,setPostData]=useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>
  {
      const getPosts= async()=>{
      const {data:res}= await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/res/getAll');
      setPosts(res);
      const p= res.map(post=>{
        return{
          title:post.title,
          startDate:post.dateBegin+" "+post.timeStart,
          endDate:post.dateBegin+" "+post.timeEnd,
          
        }
      })
      console.log(p)
      setPostData(p)
    };
    getPosts();
  },[]);


  return (
        <div className="calendars">
          <Scheduler
          data={postData} 
          >
                <ViewState/>
                <EditingState/>
                <IntegratedEditing/>
                <WeekView startDayHour={6} endDayHour={21}/>
                <DayView/>
                <Toolbar/>
                <DateNavigator />
                <TodayButton />
                <ViewSwitcher />
                <Appointments/>
                <AppointmentTooltip
                  showOpenButton
                  showCloseButton
                />
                <Resources/>
          </Scheduler>
    
        </div>
      )
  }
  export default Calendar2;
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please check now once.!

Answer (score 0):

You can see this code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/f0418b

or https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Scheduler/CustomTemplates/React/Light/